# WIX - How to Set Properties in Msi when using Custom Bootstrapper WPF UI

Tags: c#, wix

I have around 6 to 7 applications consists of websites & windows services to packed into one bundle, for that I have developed Custom UI with WPF bootstrapper application in which i need to take some inputs from the user like virtual directory name, install location, SQL credentials etc.

Now the problem is when i'm trying to set virtual directory name from wpf Ui and passing to msi from bundle by setting through msi property, the property in msi is not updating

Below is my code snippet

In product.wxs i have defined the property and directory structure like below

```
 <Property Id="TARGETDIRECTORY" Value="test"/>
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
     <Directory Id="IISROOT" Name='WebDir'>
     <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR'   Name='[TARGETDIRECTORY]'>
```

In bundle.wxs

```
<Variable bal:Overridable="yes" Name="TargetDirectory" Value="test"/>
 <MsiPackage Id="TESTSERVER" SourceFile="$(var.Gac.TEST.Setup.Server.TargetPath)" Visible="yes"  DisplayInternalUI="no">
<MsiProperty Name="TARGETDIRECTORY" Value="[TargetDirectory]"/>
       </MsiPackage>
```

In Bootstraper

```
engine.StringVariables["TargetDirectory"] = "XYZ";
```

When i install, virtual directory is creating with name TARGETDIRECTORY instead of xyz. I'm new to wix, can anyone guide me in achieving this and please let me know where i'm doing wrong

Comment: You have to pass your variables through command prompt :

Comment: This is strange to me. Even if you're not properly setting the value of [TARGETDIRECTORY] from the MsiProperty, you should be getting the default value of "test" for [TARGETDIRECTORY] during installation. Are you certain you haven't set it to "TARGETDIRECTORY" accidentally somewhere else in the install process? Would a verbose msi log help identify any potential cases of this?

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the log in detail, i have observed that property change is not happening for TargetDirectory before AppSearch Event

Answer (score 0):

```
I pass some of the properties from cmd , and some i read from xml document and set them.


using (var p = new Process())
                {
                    var info = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
                        Arguments = string.Format("/c msiexec /i \"{0}\\{6}.msi\" PATHNAME=\"{0}\" SSLCERTPATH=\"{1}\"" +
                        " MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=\":{2}\" USERPATH={3} ENVIRONMENTPATH={4} SSLCERTPASS=\"{5}\" /L*v \"{0}\\{6}Log.txt\""
                        , XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPath, environment, XmlSettings.IisUserFolderPath,
                        XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPass, msiName),
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    };
                    p.StartInfo = info;
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you provide me the sample application, how to read from xml file?

Comment: Check out the Xml Serialization in c# .You need to implement serializer and deserialiser (serialize the ur objects that u set from your form , and then deserialize the xml doc from custom action and set the values to Wix properties

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm able to set INSTALLDIR name with custom action.

In custom action, i'm setting required property values from xml